# Objective-C tab settings and whitespace style

Tags: objective-c, coding-style, whitespace

Apple's Objective-C documentation, references, and generated code seem to be totally inconsistent with their coding style. I can not  determine the "preferred" style (if one exists) for Objective-C and Cocoa source code.

Here's what I've ran into so far.

### Tab settings

Xcode's default setting is set to tabs. However, generated projects are always created with 4 spaces regardless of your tab settings. Worse, some generated code has stray tabs hanging around. Downloaded code examples seem to vary from project to project as well.

### Method definition spacing

In Apple's example code, different styles of method definition even vary within a single file. But the most common style of spacing seems to include a space between the `-` or `+` and spaces only between addition arguments. This style is also used in the Xcode reference library which leads me to believe it is the preferred style.

```
- (IBAction)reloadData:(id)sender;
- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex
```

Inconsistent variates:

```
- (IBAction) reloadData:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)reloadData:(id) sender;
-(IBAction)reloadData:(id)sender;
- (IBAction) reloadData: (id)sender;
- (id)tableView: (NSTableView *)aTableView objectValueForTableColumn: (NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn row: (NSInteger)rowIndex
```

### Brace style

Another thing that is widely inconsistent is the brace style. There are two popular styles:

Open brace on its own line:

```
  @interface Foo : NSObject
  {
  }

  - (id)init
  {
  }
```

Open brace on the same line as the method declaration:

```
  @interface Foo : NSObject {
  }

  - (id)init {
  }
```

## Question

Is there a recommended coding style for Objective-C by Apple? If not, what style do you prefer and why?

Answer (score 9):

I found that I was constantly setting the generated projects to my own preferred style, so I edited the template files to my preferences (tabs for indent, braces on a line of their own). The files are here:

`/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Project Templates/`

I select everything, get rid of all indentation with cmd-[ (as many times as the document needs) and do Edit->Format->re-indent. I have this hooked up to shift-cmd-[ for convenience.

I've seen the differences in style for example code and project templates and just assumed it was due to the age of the files being different. I guess they have had different internal coding style guides which have changed.

Here's the Google Obj-C style guide:

http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/objcguide.xml

and another nice one from CocoaDevCentral:

http://www.cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000082.php

of if you really want to follow Apple rules, the Objective C programming guide has a bunch of code examples to take rules from.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/

Comment: The last link is dead.